# How to create app with many pages on react native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I don't understand how to create app on react native with more, than 1 page. How to navigate from 1 page to other page using hyperlink? Each page in each *.js file? Can you provide me very easy example with 2 pages. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move from view to view in React Native, you need to use either Navigator or NavigatorIOS. Here are the documentation for each:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigatorios.html

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#content

Also, there are some examples of how to use them in React Native's GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer/Navigator).

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer/Navigator

Comment: Thanks. If I use NavigatorIOS it will work on Android devices or only on IOS?

Comment: NavigatorIOS will not work on Android, so if you are targeting both, or want to rewrite less, you may want to stick with Navigator, as it will work on both.

Comment: Also, here's a pretty basic example that you can play around with: https://rnplay.org/apps/R6HbAg

Comment: But I see all pages on one *.js file in example, it's ok or not?

Comment: You can either break them up into separate files, or include them all in one file, depending on how you structure your application. The larger it gets, the more likely that you will be breaking them up into separate files and folders.